# enable on-board graphics after separated graphics card broken

Tags: display, graphics-card, signal, on-board-peripheral

My separated graphics card broke so I want to enable on-board graphics. Problem is I can't do anything in the Bios because my monitor has no signal. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the broken card.
When the case is open anyway find the "CMOS clear" jumper.
Use it to reset the bios configuration to default (see the manual of the motherboard for instructions).
This should re-enable the on-board graphics, even if it was disabled previously.

Comment: You can also just remove both the power to the PC and the CMOS button battery for 10ish seconds, without having to deal with the jumper.

Comment: @PeterMaxwell That would do it too, but sometimes these batteries are a real pain to take out (really tight socket). And some motherboards don't use the regular CR2032 battery, but something that not easily recognized as a battery. Sometimes even soldered onto the motherboard.

Comment: True, that's a good point. So I guess just do which ever is easiest with that particular mobo.

Answer (score 0):

- Borrow a second separated graphics card (a working one).
- Next enter the BIOS (now visible due to the working card). Enable on-board graphics as primary.
- Shutdown, remove the borrowed card and boot from the system.
- Boot using the configuration you set in the second step.

Very easy, but assuming you can borrow a second card.

Comment: They could also just remove the dedicated graphics card, use the on-board graphics card instead, only possible if the motherboard has a dedicated video port though.

Comment: if the motherboard is set to onboard video: disabled, then he needs to barrow a graphics card 100%.

Comment: Or reset the BIOS. Which might actually be easier.

Comment: @Hennes My thoughts exactly. I didn't see your comment until after I posted my answer.

Comment: Heh. I had that happen lots of times when I try to post a somewhat long answer. :) 
Anyway. Upvoted since it does not need additional hardware.